How to parse configuration file
I have a long configuration file with a non RFC format which looks similar to ndjson but it is not. I can't figure out what format name this is and have been looking at the parslet library yet I can't figure out how to parse correctly.
Here is a piece of the config file:
node {
    lname: node_3432_ND_23
        1 {
          name: node_1
          index: 1310
          label: route_D_12_2009.11
          id: 981
          histo:
         ref: node_1/23 
          desref: 0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0          
          1 {
            name: lofta_209         
            profile: tds.1
           sutprofile: 
            enabled: true
           weight: 123         
            bufferdata {
              out: 1_3s 
              in: 1_3s
              tags {
                red: 1
                green: 3
              }
           }
          }
    }
    2 {
    }
    3 {
      dataref:
      ccd {
      }
      route {
            0.0.0.0\0 {
              face: 0.0.0.0
              name: eth.9
              type: psf
              value: 22
           }
            127.0.0.1\32 {
              face: 0.0.0.0
              name: cd/2
              type: lg
              value: 41
            }
          }
    }
}


class CSON < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:whitespace) { match('[\s\t]').repeat(1) } # Match once a space or tab
  rule(:newline)    { str("\r\n") | str("\n") }
  rule(:space)      { match('\s').repeat(1) }
  rule(:space?)     { space.maybe }
  rule(:quote)      { str('"') }
  rule(:nonquote)   { str('"').absent? >> any }
  rule(:comma)      { str(',') >> space? }
  rule(:colon)      { str(':') >> space? }
  rule(:escape)     { str('\\') >> any }
  rule(:assignment) { str('=') >> whitespace.maybe }
  rule(:integer)    { match['0-9'].repeat(1).as(:int) >> space? }
  #rule(:string)     { quote >> (escape | nonquote).repeat(1).as(:str) >> quote }
  rule(:string)     { (nonquote).repeat(1).as(:str)}
  rule(:value)      { string | integer }
  rule(:array_list) { value >> (comma >> value).repeat }
  rule(:array)      { match['\['] >> array_list.as(:array) >> match['\]'] }
  rule(:hash_pair)  { string.as(:key) >> colon >> object.as(:value) }
  rule(:hash_list)  { hash_pair >> (comma >> hash_pair).repeat }
  rule(:hash)       { match['{'] >> hash_list.as(:hash) >> match['}'] }
  rule(:chash)       { match['{'] >> any.as(:chash) >> match['}'] }
  rule(:cof)        { match('DDDD[n][e] {').repeat(1) }
  rule(:all)        { str('toto') }

  rule(:object)     { all | cof | hash | array | string | integer | chash}
  root :object
end



What does parse it correctly mean to you? Can you post the desired output?

Your code clashes with the built in JSON module and will cause a TypeError if it has been required. Use a different name unless you want to shoot yourself in the foot.

@engineersmnky i just want to parse it as ruby hash.

@max thanks. That was just an example in an empty snippet file.

I was able to find a way to parse this using parslet and a bit of pre and post processing.
Implementation could probably be cleaned up a bit but it appears to function as requested.
require 'parslet'

class CSON < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:lbrace)     { whitespace? >> str('{') >> whitespace? }
  rule(:rbrace)     { whitespace? >> str('}') >> whitespace? }
  rule(:whitespace) { match['\s\t\n'].repeat(1) }
  rule(:whitespace?) { whitespace.maybe }
  rule(:colon)      { str(':') }
  rule(:string)     { match['A-Za-z0-9_/\.\\\,'].repeat(1)}
  rule(:key)        { string }
  rule(:hash_pair)  { key.as(:key) >> colon >> whitespace? >> string.maybe.as(:value) }
  rule(:hash_list)  { object >> (whitespace? >> object).repeat }
  rule(:hash)       { lbrace >> hash_list.maybe >> rbrace }
  rule(:key_value)  { key.as(:key) >> whitespace? >> hash.as(:value) }
  rule(:empty_key)  { key.as(:key) >> colon >> match['\n'].as(:value)} 
  rule(:object)     { key_value | hash | empty_key | hash_pair | string  }
  root :object

  # could include the pre-processing of the file here as well
  def parse_to_native_hash(doc_string)
    post_process(parse(doc_string))
  end 

private 
  def post_process(h)
    result = {} 
    value = h[:value]
    result[h[:key].to_s] = if value.is_a?(Array)
      value.map { |v| post_process(v) }.reduce(&:merge)
    else
      v = value.to_s.gsub(/\n/, "")
      v == '{}' ? {} : v
    end
    result
  end
end

Usage: (Assuming the file is "config.txt")
doc = File.readlines('config.txt', chomp: true).map(&:strip).join("\n")
CSON.new.parse_to_native_hash(doc)

This results in
{"node"=>
  {"lname"=>"node_3432_ND_23",
   "1"=>
    {"name"=>"node_1",
     "index"=>"1310",
     "label"=>"route_D_12_2009.11",
     "id"=>"981",
     "histo"=>"",
     "ref"=>"node_1/23",
     "desref"=>"0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0",
     "1"=>
      {"name"=>"lofta_209",
       "profile"=>"tds.1",
       "sutprofile"=>"",
       "enabled"=>"true",
       "weight"=>"123",
       "bufferdata"=>
        {"out"=>"1_3s", "in"=>"1_3s", "tags"=>{"red"=>"1", "green"=>"3"}}}},
   "2"=>{},
   "3"=>
    {"dataref"=>"",
     "ccd"=>{},
     "route"=>
      {"0.0.0.0\\0"=>
        {"face"=>"0.0.0.0", "name"=>"eth.9", "type"=>"psf", "value"=>"22"},
       "127.0.0.1\\32"=>
        {"face"=>"0.0.0.0", "name"=>"cd/2", "type"=>"lg", "value"=>"41"}}}}}

